# LESS array loop through loop: double loop case

Tags: less

How to double loop in LESS to generate a set of mixins such as:

```
.p_0_0 {
  padding: 0rem 0rem;
}
.p_1_0 {
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}
.p_0_1 {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
.p_1_1 {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}
```

It is better to use built-in tools...

Answer (score 0):

Since LESS 3.x version LESS has `each` function, see more [here](https://lesscss.org/functions/). In this case, we can use this function to its fullest:

```
@steps: {
  0: 0rem;
  1: 1rem;
};

each(@steps, .(@valueX, @keyX, @indexX) {
  each(@steps, .(@valueY, @keyY, @indexY) {
    .p_@{keyY}_@{keyX} {
      @{valueP}: @valueY @valueX;
    }
  })
})
```

Which generates:

```
.p_0_0 {
  padding: 0rem 0rem;
}
.p_1_0 {
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}
.p_0_1 {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
.p_1_1 {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}
```